# How can i write select with join using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT 
    Przedmiot, COUNT(Ocena) 'wystawiono n ocen'
FROM
    Przedmiot
JOIN
    ocena ON przedmiot.IdPrzedmiot = Ocena.IdPrzedmiot
GROUP BY
    Przedmiot
```

How can I run this using T-SQL cursor?

this is what I have so far but it prins same row few times:(

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT Przedmiot, COUNT(Ocena) 'wystawiono n ocen'
        from Przedmiot
        join ocena 
        on przedmiot.IdPrzedmiot = Ocena.IdPrzedmiot
        group by Przedmiot
DECLARE @Przedmiot varchar(50)
DECLARE @IloscOnen varchar(50)
OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor into @Przedmiot, @IloscOnen
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN 
       print  @Przedmiot + ' - wystawiono ' + @IloscOnen + ' ocen'
          FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
       END 
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor 
go
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database name. Make your requirement bit more clear.

Comment: What have you tried and what errors have you got ?, you shouldn't have any problem declaring a cursor for this select.

Comment: I dont have any errors, it just doesnt print me an output like it does without using cursor. his is firs time I am trying to use cursor.

Comment: You can use a cursor on any select statement, but why would you want to do that? Cursors are notoriously slow and ineffective in SQL. You really should strive to avoid them.

Comment: it is just for learning purpose

Comment: A Cursor is only a way to iterate through a result set and operate on a row-by-agonizing-row basis. If you could [edit] your question to include sample data (Preferably as DDL + DML - create table and insert statements) and expected results that would help us give you an answer.

Comment: I updated first post with what I got right now, it has some errors though:(

Comment: Compare the first fetch with the second fetch. What is the difference? Might that be an issue?

Comment: count returns an int. so you should fetch that column into an int variable. don't depend on implicit conversion in your code.

Comment: yeah thanks first and 2nd fetch were not the same! works!

Comment: @JohnyS, not sure if you have already got what you are looking for here, but since you are learning cursors, wanted to share a few info regarding the same: 1> Like Zohar Peled has said already, in SQL Server, where possible, try to rather use SET based operations for receiving far better performance than computing row-by-row approach (cursors) due to the way SQL Server internal architecture is set-up (Oracle is different in this aspect), 2> Try to use LOCAL and FAST_FORWARD cursor rather than the default GLOBAL cursors for better performance, unless you need to track back the previous rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `FETCH` the values into your variables:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT Przedmiot, COUNT(Ocena) 'wystawiono n ocen'
        from Przedmiot
        join ocena 
        on przedmiot.IdPrzedmiot = Ocena.IdPrzedmiot
        group by Przedmiot
DECLARE @Przedmiot varchar(50)
DECLARE @IloscOnen varchar(50)
OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor into @Przedmiot, @IloscOnen
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN 
       print  @Przedmiot + ' - wystawiono ' + @IloscOnen + ' ocen'
          FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor into @Przedmiot, @IloscOnen
       END 
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor 
go
```